# Get object property stored in listview from another page wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, parameter-passing, listviewitem

This is my class :

```
class Discussion
{
    public String name {get; set;}
    public String discussionId { get; set; }
    public List<Message> liste {get; set;}

    public Discussion(String name, String discussionId)
    {
        this.name = name;
        this.discussionId = discussionId;
    }
```

I create some instance of this class and I store them in a listview.
When I double click on a listViewItem (it only show the name property), I navigate to another page that need to know the discussionId.

How can I get this property ?
This is how I navigate to the new page :

```
public partial class DiscussionPage : Page
{
    public DiscussionPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        try
        {
            SqlDataReader read = Broker.sqlcommand("SELECT DISCUSSION.TITRE, USER1.NOM FROM dbo.DISCUSSION, dbo.USER1 WHERE USER1.ID = DISCUSSION.ID_CREER;").ExecuteReader();
            while (read.Read())
            {
                Discussion d = new Discussion(read["TITRE"].ToString(), read["NOM"].ToString());
                listDiscussion.Items.Add(d);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {

            throw;
        }
    }

    private void ListView_MouseDoubleClick(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        DependencyObject clickedObj = (DependencyObject)e.OriginalSource;

        while (clickedObj != null && clickedObj != listDiscussion)
        {
            if (clickedObj.GetType() == typeof(ListViewItem))
            {
                Discussion selectedDiscussion = (Discussion)listDiscussion.SelectedItem;
                this.NavigationService.Navigate(new MessagePage(selectedDiscussion));
                break;
            }
            clickedObj = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(clickedObj);
        }
    }

    private void openAddDiscussion(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        addDiscussion add = new addDiscussion();
        add.Show();
    }
}
```

I need to know discussionId to load the content of this page :

```
public partial class MessagePage : Page
{
    public MessagePage(Discussion SelectedDiscussion)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        try
        {
            SqlDataReader read = Broker.sqlcommand("SELECT MESSAGE.TEXT FROM dbo.MESSAGE WHERE MESSAGE.ID_POSSEDER = \'" + SelectedDiscussion.discussionId + "\'").ExecuteReader();
            while (read.Read())
            {
                Message m = new Message(read["TEXT"].ToString());
                showMessage.Items.Add(m);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            throw;
        }
    }
}
```

Full code added, still don't work with SelectedValue:

> incoherent Accessibility: parameter type 'commApp.Classes.Discussion' is less accessible than method 'commApp.MessagePage.MessagePage (commApp.Classes.Discussion)'

Comment: You haven't shown how you add items to the ListView, but you should add Discussion objects, not ListViewItems. The usual way of doing this is to create a view model class that exposes a property of type `ObservableCollection<Discussion>` and bind the ListView's `ItemsSource` property to that collection. See [Data Templating Overview](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742521.aspx) for a detailed explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Without [a good, *minimal*, *complete* code example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), it's impossible to know for sure what the best approach is.

However, if you have set your `ListView` up correctly and the `ItemsSource` is a collection of `Discussion` objects, then by default the `SelectedValue` property will return the `Discussion` object instance reference that corresponds to the selected item in the list.

In that case, you would just change your code to look like this:

```
private void ListView_MouseDoubleClick(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    DependencyObject clickedObj = (DependencyObject)e.OriginalSource;

    while (clickedObj != null && clickedObj != listDiscussion)
    {
        if (clickedObj.GetType() == typeof(ListViewItem))
        {
            Discussion selectedDiscussion = (Discussion)listDiscussion.SelectedValue;
            this.NavigationService.Navigate(new MessagePage(selectedDiscussion));
            break;
        }
        clickedObj = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(clickedObj);
    }
}
```

I.e. just use the `SelectedValue` property instead of `SelectedItem`. If you have deviated from the default by setting the `SelectedValuePath` property, then you will want to use the `ItemContainerGenerator` object to get the correct reference:

```
private void ListView_MouseDoubleClick(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    DependencyObject clickedObj = (DependencyObject)e.OriginalSource;

    while (clickedObj != null && clickedObj != listDiscussion)
    {
        if (clickedObj.GetType() == typeof(ListViewItem))
        {
            Discussion selectedDiscussion =
                (Discussion)listDiscussion.ItemContainerGenerator
                    .ItemFromContainer((ListViewItem)listDiscussion.SelectedItem);

            this.NavigationService.Navigate(new MessagePage(selectedDiscussion));
            break;
        }
        clickedObj = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(clickedObj);
    }
}
```

If neither of those seem to apply in your case, please edit your question so that it includes a good code example, with which a better answer can be provided.